# How realy work Varargs in java?

Tags: java, casting, variadic-functions

I am now learning Varargs in java.
I wrote this method:

```
 public static void vrati(Object... arguments){
    for(Object i : arguments)

    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Then I called the method:

```
 main.vrati(8,2,"String");
```

So my question is: does varargs cast primitive types to object?
Because I have mixed in int and String in this method call and can access them like is one object.

Comment: This process is called autoboxing. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html for an introduction. It has nothing to do with varargs.

Comment: No, not cast.  All the primitives in Java have wrapper classes (e.g., int and Integer).  Think of it as auto boxing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So my question does varargs cast primitive types to object?

It casts to the type of the array. If you have

```
a(int... ints)
```

They will be `int`

and if you have

```
b(double... doubles)
```

they will be doubles even if you write `b (1, 2.0f, 10L)`

If you have an

```
c(Object... obj)
```

it will autobox primitives. This is not a feature of var-args but how types are autoboxed as needed anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Varargs are the variable number of arguments. It allows arguments from 0 to unlimited. Varargs are denoted by ... (triple dots). Varargs must be the last argument of the function. Consider the following program :

```
class Test
{
    static void display(Object ... o)
    {   
        for(Object o1 : o)
            System.out.print(o1+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        display();
        display(10,20,30,40,50);
        display(10.2f,20.3f,3.14f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Varargs" are mainly syntactic sugar.

So

```
Whatever...
```

turns into

```
Whatever[]
```

In other words: the method takes an **array** of the Vararg-type you are using.

And the compiler makes sure that each and any invocation of a vararg-method receives an array (so the compiler is inserting the `new Whatever[]` more or less for you).

And please note: the fact that your example relies on **auto-boxing** has nothing to do with the fact that you are also using varargs.

If the signature of your method would have been `Object[]` instead, it works the same way (minus the little thingy that you have to pass an array now, instead of just listing your values, separated by comma).